# Undefined variable when submitting an ng-change

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to store a variable from the date type input in html using angularJs. I've done this previously in this application with select tags instead of input tags and its working fine so I know all the data is correct.

My input code:

```
 <input type="date" ng-model="x.TARGET_DATE" ng-change="updateTargetDate(x.TASK_ID)">
```

My function code:

```
   $scope.updateTargetDate = function (TASK_ID) {
 console.log($scope.TASK_ID);
```

};

In the console.log I get = undefined

I have this working in the column before this so I know its not data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TASK_ID` is the name of function's parameter. It is not a $scope variable I guess, so you should access like this:

```
   $scope.updateTargetDate = function (TASK_ID) {
       console.log(TASK_ID);
   };
```

Comment: Thanks, not happy I spent so long on that haha